# jquery - How to add image to the Select2 dropdown list with data retreived from MySQL and PHP through AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I want to add an image in front of the options in the searchable dropdown list I made. The list is populated with data from MySQL database retrieved via PHP and AJAX. I am using the Select2 plugin for this problem, and I succeeded in making it work with simple data from the database, but I don't know how to add an image (link to the image is stored in the database) to the option. I read this [article](https://select2.org/dropdown), but I don't know how to implement that information into my code.

This is what I made so far:

**HTML**

```
<select id="js-hieroglyph-code-select" name="hieroglyph-code-input" data-width="100%">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select hieroglyph code</option>
</select>
```

**JS/Jquery**

```
$("#js-hieroglyph-code-select").select2({
    ajax : {
        url : "./includes/individual_retrieve_scripts/retrieve_hieroglyph_undefined.script.php",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        delay : 250,
        data : function(params){
            return {
                hieroglyphCodeValue : params.term
            };
        },
        processResults : function(response){
            return {
                results : response
            };
        },
        cache : true
    } 
});
```

**PHP**

```
$data = array(["id" => "0", "text" => "Hieroglyph without code"]);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchData)) {
    $data[] = array(
        "id" => $row["undefined_hieroglyph_code"],
        "text" => $row["undefined_hieroglyph_code"]
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

I purposely left out the database query part of the PHP code for the sake of convenience, but I think it is not important for the problem here.

I thought about concatenating image link data and text data in PHP and then separate it in Javascript, but this is only an idea, and I don't know how to use that separated data further. Something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchData)) {
    $data[] = array(
        "id" => $row["undefined_hieroglyph_code"],
        "text" => $row["undefined_hieroglyph_code"]."/".$row["image_link"]
    );
}
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at select2 templateResult option [here](https://select2.org/dropdown)
You should first add the URL of the image as a separate key in your results and then use it in the function that templates your select2

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchData)) {
$data[] = array(
    "id" => $row["undefined_hieroglyph_code"],
    "text" => $row["undefined_hieroglyph_code"],
    "imageUrl" => $row["image_link"]
);}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not understand where and how I should put this ``templateResult`` in my JS code so it could work.